# facebook login blank page

Tags: facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I use parse sdk and want to implement FB login but when I hit the button to login a popup open and if I didn't login in fb before it ask me for credential after that a blank page will show with this address 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=%7Bappid%7D&client_id{client id}&display=popup&domain={domain}&e2e=%7B%7D&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D29%23cb%3Df2356881fe8e6bc%26domain%3D{domain}%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F{domain}%252Ff1d6980bbb127d2%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df17ee4a3b5fd2e8&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&scope=email%2Cpublish_stream&sdk=joey

And it didnt auto close and redirect to my webpage.

At this blank page popup, view source and see some js: var message = "cb=f1a6be948fefda&domain={domain}&origin=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fjebsenwine.dev.cleargo.com\u00252Ffe2018a8b499c4&relation=opener&frame=f7e1c0c9232fd2&access_token={access token}&base_domain=", origin = "http://{domain}", domain = "{domain}"; document.domain='facebook.com';(function(){var a=window.opener||window.parent,b='fb_xdm_frame_'+location.protocol.replace(':','');function c(){try{a.frames[b].proxyMessage(message,origin);}catch(e){setTimeout(c,100);}}function d(){_fbNative.postMessage(message,origin);}if(window==top&&/FBAN/\w+;/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){if(window._fbNative&&__fbNative.postMessage){d();}else window.addEventListener('fbNativeReady',d);}else c();})();